# Magento 2 Change order of Tabs on product page

Tags: magento2, layout, product-view, tabs

I have added **catalog_product_view.xml** in the location **app/code/design/frontend/kh/custom/Magento_Catalog/layout**

Set the priority for the tabs for the product detail page, but its is not working properly.

Code is given below :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">4</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
            <referenceBlock name="product.attributes">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">2</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
            <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
            <block class="KH\Hello\Block\Hello" name="new.tab" template="KH_Hello::hello.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
               <arguments>
                   <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">New Tab</argument>
                   <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">3</argument>
               </arguments>
           </block>
        </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking that code out the `product.info.details` referenceBlock. This is my code which is working as intended:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <!-- Reorder tabs (using "before/after" doesn't work with groups) -->
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">10</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">50</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

The only other difference is this code is using multiples of ten.

Comment: I used same code as you provided but no luck. I am using Magento2.2 version. If I tried to pass additional argument like <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">New Review</argument> It display title of Review tab to New Review.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the code out of product.info.details worked, and also applying it to a referenceBlock rather than the actual block in product.info.details. So mine now looks something like

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.description" remove="true" />
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom_template.tab" before="-" template="product/view/custom_template.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
        <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">About</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.composition" after="-" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
        <arguments>
            <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getComposition</argument>
            <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">composition</argument>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">composition</argument>
            <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Nutrition</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>

<!-- PRIORITY WORKS HERE -->
<referenceBlock name="custom_template.tab" template="product/view/custom_template.phtml" >
    <arguments><argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">1</argument></arguments>
</referenceBlock>
<referenceBlock name="product.info.composition" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" >
    <arguments><argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">2</argument></arguments>
</referenceBlock>
<referenceBlock name="reviews.tab">
    <arguments><argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">3</argument></arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```